# Check if next picture exists array

Tags: php

```
<div id="full">
  <?php $i=0; $j=1; foreach ($array as $image) { ?>
    <div id="image<?php echo $i;?>" 
         class="img bg-img<?php echo $j;?>">
      <img src="<?php echo $image['image']; ?>" ></img>
    </div>
  <?php $j++; $i++;} ?>         
</div>
```

How do i check if next picture exists or not

Comment: What do you mean "if next picture exists?" Do you need to check whether the file actually exists on disk?  Then you can use `if(file_exists($filename))` in your PHP.  Otherwise, please explain what you're after.

Comment: images are been taken from an xml file and i need to know when there are no more pictures to say stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="full">
  <?php $i=0; foreach ($array as $image): ?>

      <?php if(file_exists($image['image'])): ?>

      <div id="image<?php echo $i;?>" 
         class="img bg-img<?php echo $i+1;?>">
      <img src="<?php echo $image['image']; ?>" ></img>
      </div>

    <?php else: break; ?>

  <?php $i++; endforeach ?>         
</div>
```

This will check if the image exists, and echo it if does. If not it will `break` out of the loop (essentially cancelling it. Depending on the data you may want to use a `continue` in place of break

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the file exists with the php function file_exists()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Answer (score 0):

like

```
if(file_exists($image['image']))
{
  echo  xyz....;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(file_exists($array[$i + 1]['image'])) { ... }
```